# building cross binutils fr30-unknown-none unsupported

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, configure, binutils

I am trying to build a cross binutilsfor fr30. After running the configure command :

```
./configure --target=fr30 --enable-cgen-maint --prefix=/<long_path>/myBinutils/new_build_fr30_cgen/
```

I run make command and got the next error :

```
** BFD does not support target fr30-unknown-none.
*** Look in bfd/config.bfd for supported targets.
make[1]: *** [configure-bfd] Error 1
```

how do I find the unknown-none ? any advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--target` configure option is expecting a [target triplet](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html) of the form *cpu-vendor-os*.

If you look at the big case statement in *bfd/config.bfd* that the error message is pointing you at, you'll see that for fr30 the supported target triplets match `fr30-*-elf`.

For example, configuring with `./configure --target=fr30-elf ...` will get you to success or your next problem, as this abbreviation is canonicalised to a suitable triplet (by *config.sub*):

```
$ ./config.sub fr30-elf
fr30-unknown-elf
```

Hopefully with such a configuration, you'll end up with `fr30-elf-ld`, etc.